# Does MacOS 10.15 still have a file for the webcam inside: /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/?

Tags: macos, webcam

I was searching for a solution for a "broken" camera on a MacBook 12" and found a source that said that this file `AppleCamera.plugin` should be inside this folder: `/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/` is this still the case for newer versions of MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there's only plugins-info.txt in `/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL` on macOS Catalina ProductVersion: 10.15.4